# How to check if SharePoint Content database is in unsupported mode?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, query, sql-server-2008

Everywhere I looked, people keep saying:

*Do not modify the content database in any maner other than using SharePoint or the db will be considered as in unsupported mode.*

That means to me that there is necessarily a way to check if the so called changes were made.
Is there a special trigger fired anytime a non SharePoint API  querying the database ?

In [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e1f01e2-2c99-4f03-8b75-54afbd8fe2cd/how-to-determine-if-sharepoint-content-database-is-in-support-mode?forum=sharepointadminprevious) someone said:

"*the only way for PSS/Microsoft to know is if they saw active interference from the read operation on that database.  They would not be able to tell after-the-fact.*"

That's a joke right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all data in SharePoint databases and still be in supported mode. It's when you change a value or delete a row that the databases will be in unsupported mode. Even if you try to hide the operation by deleting auditing, truncate logs or any other "smart" move on can tell if the change was made by SharePoint or not.

Often operations in SharePoint databases happen in one transaction affecting several tables and more than one database. If you make changes to one, but not the other MS can trace that operation wasn't made by SharePoint.

It's not a joke, and SP databases are anything but funny.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Benny. It does anticipate the next question coming after the one in the title. It's very usefull.  Nevertheless, it doesn't answer to the main question. ( i.e How do I check the state? ). Typically, if it's already in an unsupported state, it doesn't matter anymore to make changes on it.

Comment: @ameliapond You need to be a SQL Server expert and knowing where to look in SharePoint databases to tell if you are in supported mode or not. Even with my MCSE I really can't tell.